# Where is the cityscape in this recent photo, probably in Malaysia?

Tags: identify-this, where-on-earth, malaysia

My friend has recently visited Malaysia and sent me this photo. They do not know where exactly it is, but has given the following details:

- photo was recently taken (within past year)
- it is near a university
- in Malaysia, somewhere near Seremban
- train track in the image might be for RapidKL

I've tried cropping the potentially iconic tower in the background and (separately) the colorful building and doing a reverse image search. I did not found any resemblance using this method.

Where exactly was this photo taken?

[image]

Comment: In the middle of the picture you can see the Petronas twin towers and the observation tower on the right seems to be Menara Kuala Lumpur.

Comment: The building on the left is Kuala Lumpur City Hall. So the picture was taken somewhere a little bit East of there, probably one of the towers just on the other side of the road, probably Bank Negara or the building housing the Centre for Executive Education.

Comment: I've raised this on https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7184/should-all-where-was-this-picture-taken-posts-be-allowed because it all seems quite suspicious to me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8473/can-we-close-some-identify-this-questions-for-being-stalkery

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is in Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia, taken from a building just opposite the Kuala Lumpur City Hall.

Here is the closest Google Street View I could get (click to get to Street View):

[image]

Note that you can barely see the top of the Petronas towers above the red building in the middle, like in your picture. The building with the blue roof also aligns with the AIA building like yours.

It's evidently taken from a higher location, so most certainly this building (click to get to Google Maps):

[image]

On your picture, you can see:

- Kuala Lumpur City Hall
- AIA Capsquare
- The Petronas Towers
- Menara Kuala Lumpur observation tower

The railway visible is shared by the Ampang and Sri Petaling Lines.

Sadly, there's no decent 3D satellite view in Google Maps or Apple Maps for Kuala Lumpur.

Here's a link to a photo probably taken from the same place, but sadly towards the ground: https://goo.gl/maps/JvfupeuRoXxSRK757